# Adding fields to Excel, and Exporting a Subform in Access.

Tags: excel, ms-access, filtering

Sorry! I am new here, and this is my first time ever posting.  I think it is amazing how helpful these communities are.  Okay, I have 2 questions ( I know, I'm double dipping, I am trying to complete my project before I leave for my new job)

- List item
- I have a list of 1500 items for each of our 536 vendors, our original
  vendor item list from last year, had only 1046 items, how can I
  quickly add the extra 400+ items to each vendor list? In Excel
- I am then inputting all of this into Access to keep a database of our
  vendors and their product pricing, I would like to create a form that
  will allow me to filter by such fields as vendor name, rate year, and
  vendor number.
- When selected from a drop down or combo box, it would    display all
  1500 items from that vendor.  From here I would like to    export
  these filtered result to excel to send to our vendor to ask    for
  updated prices.  I have been wracking my brain as for the best
  method to do this.  Please assist.

Comment: Do you want to do this programatically or manually?

Comment: programatically, pref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but here's the one I thought of.

1. Create a table with the 150 items for each vendor.  Create a blank field in the table for vendor name.
2. Create another table with the vendor name.
3. Grab the vendor name from the second table and plug it in with a variable into the dataset you grab from the first table.  Use that to write a create table query.
4. Use table 3 to build your form on.

Comment: how do i plug it with a variable?

Comment: Create a recordset with data from the table in #1. Then update the vendor name with the name from the table in #2 within that recordset

Comment: Could you mark the answer correct and mark a positive sign on my answer if you liked it?  Thanks, Charles

Comment: i tried to do an up but it wont let me post it, because i am too new..?